# "One better not try to do sth": correction or incorrect?

Tags: expressions

I have read the expression [you better not try](https://www.google.com/search?q=you+better+not+try) in several texts. Is it ok to switch *you* with *one*? I.e.,:

> One better not try to do [...].

Here is an example of a full sentence:

> United Airlines' website sometimes doesn't allow customers to cancel the ticket, but instead ask to call the customer service. This means **one better not try to** cancel after 23 hours and 59 minutes after the purchase of the flight ticket.

I couldn't find any use of "one better not try to" on Google.

Comment: You can find a few examples here: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22one+better+not+try+to%22

Comment: @stangdon thanks, good catch!

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should be *One **had** better not [do that]*. See earlier question [Why is it "had" in "I had better get going"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114179/why-is-it-had-in-i-had-better-get-going)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, *one* has a formal quality, and it fits better with *had better not X*, or *you'd better not X.*

*You better not X*. is informal.

It's not a question of a rule, but style consistency might explain why no instances of *one better not X* were found.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure I understood correctly, I should instead write "one had better not try to cancel [...]" in the example given in the question?

Comment: I think so, as a matter of style, not a hard rule.

Comment: 'You better' is very informal and colloquial; 'you'd better' is less colloquial, and 'you had better' is most formal and standard.

Comment: Tsk. *You **had** better not teach learners utterances that don't even include a proper active verb!*